# Database allocates new Space from disk even 160 GB space is available on Database

Tags: sql-server

I am Running a Merge Statement to fill new Columns in a Table 
Space (estimated Size 10 GB of Data). 
On the Database there are 160 GB available. But it doesnt take it from there. It allocates new Space from Disk. Dont understand this.

No other user on this Databse:
Source Table 22 Mio Datasets

Execution Plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryTfRhA8E

```
MERGE [_QUELLDATEN].dbo.[dwh_PR_AUFTRAG] as Target
USING(
SELECT as aums_pos_id ,
artikel_muster, 
artikel_marke,
artikel_gender,
artikel_sortimentsbereich,
artikel_produkttyp_1,
artikel_produkttyp_2,
artikel_saisoneinsatz,
artikel_verpackung
FROM [guest].[PR_AUFTRAG_DWH_608]
) AS source
ON(Source.aums_pos_id=Target.aums_pos_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET
    artikel_muster=source.artikel_muster,
    artikel_marke=source.artikel_marke,
    artikel_gender=source.artikel_gender,
    artikel_sortimentsbereich  = source.artikel_sortimentsbereich,
    artikel_produkttyp_1  = source.artikel_produkttyp_1,
    artikel_produkttyp_2  = source.artikel_produkttyp_2,
    artikel_saisoneinsatz  = source.artikel_saisoneinsatz,
    artikel_verpackung  = source.artikel_verpackung,
    [LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] = GETDATE(),
    [MODIFIED_BY_USER] = 'jbl_DWH_608'
    ;
```

Target Table Clustered Index AUMS_POS_ID, Partitioned by Erfassdatum, Non Clustered Index Kunde_ID
Source Table: Clustered Index AUMS_POS_ID

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Without a LOT more information this is nearly impossible to answer. It could be a whole list of reasons.

Comment: SQL Server 2014. The Target Table is partitioned.

Comment: Those details should be part of the question. But seriously, that is nowhere near enough info. What is the query you are using? Are other users in the system. What does the execution plan look like? What are the table and index definitions involved. You know...the kinds of details you need to help with this type of thing.

Comment: You need to post the execution plan. Just sticking the text in here is not going to be helpful at all. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ You are going to have to put some effort into this. Nobody has a magic mirror we can just determine what the issue is with no information. Where is your merge statement? What about the tables involved?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55047050/edit) your question instead of shoving stuff into comments. The formatting is horrific in comments.